# iAdSuite not working

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad

Ive downloaded Apple's iAd code examples [iAdSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198) and when I compiled it to both the simulator and the device (4.1) I never see an ad. Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I'm based in Sydney where iAd is not currently working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem last week. It was a problem on Apples side since it works again since a few days without any changes on my side.

Do you still have problems receiving test ads?

Comment: Hey, yeh still not working. Did you sign up for iAds with Apple? I've read that you have to set up bank details etc before this works, is this correct?

Comment: @daidal yes. Any app running on iOS 4.0 or later can display test ads using the iAD SDK. iOS Developer Program members can join the iAd Network, after which they can submit apps which will be capable of displaying live ads.

Comment: Also, when you actually publish your app, you won't be able to see the ads because you're in Sydney (tough luck mate... I'm in Sydney too).

Comment: @the_great_monnkey have you seen the ads in testing though? this may be the problem: my location

Answer (score 0):

@huber_th I think you're right, delivery of test ads from Apple is erratic at times, for hours and even days. Testing can be time-consuming to put it mildly.